# How to save workspace on Matlab 2016b when it says 'Cannot save. Folder is read-only'

Tags: matlab

I am saving matrices in the current folder in the trial version of MATLAB. Error it shows is: Save operation  failed. Folder is read only'
How to save?

Comment: What folder is your current folder? It's clearly read only so either save to another folder or make the  folder not read only.

Comment: It's not getting saved in any folder.

Comment: It tries to save into the current folder (`pwd`) if you don't specify one

Comment: I am currently working in /bin folder and tried to save it there.

Comment: Right, that's a protected folder so change directories using `cd` (`cd('~')`) and save it somewhere where you have permission to write

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked!! :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, MATLAB attempts to save the file in the current working directory. You can determine what your current working directory using `pwd`

```
pwd
```

The error is stating that you don't have the necessary permission to write to this folder. You can either change your current working directory using `cd`

```
cd('/folder/you/can/write/to')
```

Or specify the full file path when saving

```
filename = fullfile('folder', 'you', 'can', 'write', 'to.mat');
save(filename)
```